# Distinct values in Access?

Tags: ms-access, distinct-values

I'm working on a query in Access, but I'm really struggling to return a count of unique rows, and similarly a sum of unique values.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT SiteOrders.CustomerID, Count(SiteOrders.ID) AS CountOfID, Sum(SiteOrders.Total) AS SumOfTotal, Sum(SiteOrderItems.Total) AS BrandTotal, Sum(SiteOrderItems.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM SiteProducts INNER JOIN (SiteOrderItems INNER JOIN SiteOrders ON SiteOrderItems.OrderID = SiteOrders.ID) ON SiteProducts.ID = SiteOrderItems.ProductID
WHERE (((SiteProducts.Brand)="1") AND ((SiteOrders.OrderDate)>#4/1/2017# And (SiteOrders.OrderDate)<#4/1/2020#) AND ((SiteOrders.Paid)=True))
GROUP BY SiteOrders.CustomerID
ORDER BY SiteOrders.CustomerID;
```

The two fields where I want distinct values are a count on SiteOrders.ID and a sum on SiteOrders.Total.

Many thanks

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables. Total should not be a field in SiteOrders table. Total should be calculated from SiteOrderItems records.

Comment: Build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in textboxes.

Comment: Is Brand a text field? If it is number, don't put parameter in quote marks.

Comment: Do you want to include 4/1/2017 records? Exclude 4/1/2020 records? Consider `OrderDate BETWEEN #4/1/2017# AND #3/31/2020#`.

Answer (score 0):

Need nested query for aggregation of SiteOrders. Consider:

```
SELECT SiteOrders.CustomerID, Sum(SiteOrderItems.Quantity) AS SumQuantity, 
Sum(SiteOrderItems.Total) AS SumTotal, Query1.CountOrderID, Query1.SumOrderTotal
FROM (SELECT CustomerID, Count(ID) AS CountOrderID, Sum(Total) AS SumOrderTotal
     FROM SiteOrders
     WHERE (((OrderDate) Between #4/1/2017# And #3/31/2020#) AND ((Paid)=True))
     GROUP BY CustomerID) AS Query1 
INNER JOIN (SiteOrders INNER JOIN (SiteProducts INNER JOIN SiteOrderItems 
ON SiteProducts.ID = SiteOrderItems.ProductID) 
ON SiteOrders.ID = SiteOrderItems.OrderID) 
ON Query1.CustomerID = SiteOrders.CustomerID
GROUP BY SiteOrders.CustomerID, Query1.CountOrderID, Query1.SumOrderTotal;
```